# Problem when sending data to FLASK using AJAX. How do I get some error message?

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, sqlalchemy, fetch

I am following a Udacity tutorial for Flask-Python web development. I keep getting the debug message `Something is wrong` which is a part of the catch block in the script part of the client code. And no new data gets added to my database. I have gone through every line of code in the tutorial and it matches but surprisingly I don't get the intended result. What am I doing incorrectly?

The code so far that I have is:

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://postgres:admin123@localhost:5432/todoapp'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    __tablename__='todos'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo:{self.id}, Descript:{self.description}>'

db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data = Todo.query.all())

@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    description_val = request.get_json()['description']
    todo = Todo(description = description_val)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        'description': todo.description
        })

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <script>
        .hidden{
            display:none;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="description" />
        <input type="submit" name="Create" />
    </form>
    <div id="error" class="hidden">Something went wrong</div>
    <ul id="todos">
        {% for d in data %}
        <li>{{ d.description }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <script>
            document.getElementbyId('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                fetch('/todos/create',{
                    method : 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }

                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();                 
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse) {
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                    const liItem = document.createElement('LI');
                    liItem.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(liItem);
                    document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';

                })
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML form, change `<input type="text" name="description" />`

to   `<input type="text" id="description" />`

because you are getting the description using the getElemenyById, and you have it set as name.